# How do I show the series $\sum{\frac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I show the series $\sum{\dfrac{1}{\log(n)^{\log(n)}}}$ converges?

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes it is. I know it converges but don't know how to prove. Thanks for the fast reply and clarification.

Comment: Comparison test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test

Comment: Thanks. Which series should I use to compare?

Answer (score 11):

We have

$$(\ln n)^{\ln n}=\exp(\ln n(\ln(\ln n))=n^{\ln(\ln n)}\ge n^2\;\text{for sufficiently large}\; n$$
so by comparison with $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try Cauchy's condensation test, which says that if $f$ is non-increasing and non-negative, then $\sum f(n)$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^{n} f(2^{n})$ converges. This test gives a pretty neat comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the Cauchy Condensation Test pretty easily here.